# Encoding ogg vorbis sound file with avconv using same codec as Audacity

Tags: avconv, audacity, ogg-vorbis

For a website I am working on, I am trying to encode **wav** files to **ogg** (vorbis) using **avconv**. It seems like in some browsers, the resulting ogg files are not decoded properly. However, I figured out that if I encode my files using **Audacity**, they work fine everywhere. I thought this might be a matter of which coded used, so I would like to know if there is a way to tell avconv to use the same codecs as Audacity!?

In case it can help, here is a bit more infos :

The **avconv** command I am currently using : `avconv -i sounds/wav/bass-0.wav -acodec libvorbis -q:a 5 sounds/ogg/bass-0.ogg`

And here is the output of **avprobe** comparing two files, the one on top is encoded with avconv, the one at the bottom with Audacity :

```
$> avprobe sounds/ogg/bass-0.ogg; avprobe sounds/ogg/bass-1.ogg
avprobe version 0.8.10-6:0.8.10-0ubuntu0.13.10.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Feb  6 2014 20:53:28 with gcc 4.8.1
Input #0, ogg, from 'sounds/ogg/bass-0.ogg':
  Duration: 00:00:03.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 142 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 160 kb/s
    Metadata:
      TITLE           : bass 01
      ITRK            : 1
      ENCODER         : Lavf53.21.1
avprobe version 0.8.10-6:0.8.10-0ubuntu0.13.10.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Feb  6 2014 20:53:28 with gcc 4.8.1
Input #0, ogg, from 'sounds/ogg/bass-1.ogg':
  Duration: 00:00:03.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 120 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 160 kb/s
    Metadata:
      TITLE           : vox 05
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems very odd, would you consider testing as well with *oggenc*. This can be found in the vorbis tools package:

```
sudo apt-get install vorbis-tools
```

This might then point the finger at avconv if the oggenc version is ok on your website.